# Update element on map depending on other update

Tags: dictionary, elixir, updates

I want to do update a map doing the following:

```
def updateInfo() do
  person = %{ person | name : "new name", age : person.age +1, observation : changeObs(person.age)}
end

def changeObs(age), when age >= 18, do: "Adult"
def changeObs(age), do: "kid"
```

If I updateInfo() and the age is 17, I would expect the person to change the observation to "Adult". But it is not working. I thought the updates of the map were done sequentially, but apparently not, so I cannot rely on the fact that the age now is 18. I can do this if I split the update like so:

```
person = %{ person | name : "new name", age : person.age +1}
person = %{ person | observation : changeObs(person.age)}
```

Is there a way to keep it all the update in one line, relying on previous updates of the attributes on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the syntax of updating maps uses colons, not equal signs. Your code raises `SyntaxError` exception.

There are plenty of ways to accomplish the task as oneliner:

```
person = with age <- person.age + 1,
          do: %{person | age: age, 
                         observation: (if age >= 18, do: "Adult", else: "Kid")}
```

Or:

```
person = (age = person.age + 1;
          %{person | age: age, 
                     observation: (if age >= 18, do: "Adult", else: "Kid")})
```

Or a pipe chain:

```
{_, person} = person
              |> Map.put(:age, person.age + 1)
              |> Map.get_and_update(:age, fn age ->
                   {age, age + 1}
                 end)
```

The idiomatic would be the last one. My fave would be the first one.

Comment: The last one won't work properly because `changeObs` will be called with an old age value, not the new one.

Comment: @JustMichael indeed, thanks, fixed with [`Map.get_and_update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#get_and_update/3).

Comment: Thanks for the correction about the colons. I really like the with statement approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as far as I can tell, you can just cache the new value in a variable:

```
new_age = person.age + 1
person = %{ person | name: "new name", age: new_age, observation: changeObs(new_age)}
```

Or you could piple the changes like this:

```
person
|> Map.put(:name, "new_name")
|> Map.put(:age, new_age)
|> Map.put(:observation, changeObs(new_age))
```